# How can I use LaTeX in Scrivener?

Tags: rendering, scrivener

I am doing some writing and using Scrivener to organize it.  I would like to be able to use LaTeX formulas and have it rendered correctly, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: latex is a self standing typesetting system and isn't designed to produce fragments of typeset output that can be embedded in other typesetters, so looking at the wikipedia entry for scrivener I doubt any real integration is possible (or at least if it is it would be a question for the scrivener developers to integrate tex markup into their word processor input)

Comment: You can output to latex from Scrivener.  Its a kludge, but it can be done. https://www.literatureandlatte.com/web/forum/viewtopic.php?t=50387

Comment: There's a painless way to do it by using Scrivener AND not-using it at the same time. Just drop me a note for more details, e.g. by commenting here.